# Rasa error with slot, how can i fix that?

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-sdk

I have this in actions.py :

from rasa_sdk import Action
from rasa_sdk.events import SlotSet
from langdetect import detect

class LanguageDetectionAction(Action):
def name(self):
return "language_detection_action"

```
def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
    user_input = tracker.latest_message.get("text")
    detected_language = detect(user_input)
    print(tracker.get_slot("detected_language"))
    dispatcher.utter_message("joke")
    return SlotSet("detected_language", detected_language)
```

and that's my domain:

responses:
utter_greet:
- condition:
- type: slot
name: detected_language
value: "en"
text: "Thank you for signing up! What do you need help with?"
- condition:
- type: slot
name: detected_language
value: "ar"
text: "مرحبا"

and thats my story :

- story: Language-based Greeting
  steps:

  - intent: greet
  - action: language_detection_action
  - action: utter_greet

I need this code to work